# Mustache on input looses the keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I've a login page in javascript (jquery) and **templated with Mustache.**

The javscript adds html content to the page (basically a common header) and **at the end i do a Mustache.to_html** to change the texts into the right ones in the language specified (i use Mustache as a simple multilanguage solution).

In this last step, **all the keypress events won't work**.

If I remove the Mustache.to_html, it works.

login.html (gcf_generals_post.js is where the Mustache call are, and login.js is where the keypress events are bind):

```
...
<!-- Personalitzacions -->
<script src="../js_gcf/gcf_generals.js"></script>
<script src="../js_gcf/gcf_generals_pre.js"></script>
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
<script src="../js_gcf/gcf_generals_post.js"></script>

</head>
...
```

login.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#user").val(localStorage.usuari);
    $("#remember")[0].checked = localStorage.recordarLogin;

    /* Carreguem el header comú del portal*/
    $("#gcf_header").load("thor_header_simple.html");

    $("#remember").click(function() {
            localStorage.recordarLogin = $("#remember")[0].checked;
    });
    $('#user').keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which === 13) {
                    $('#password').focus();
            }
    });
    $('#password').keypress(function(e){
            if(e.which === 13) {
                    $('#gcf_bLogin').click();
            }
    });

    $("#gcf_bLogin").click(function() {
            sessionStorage.usuari = $("#user").val();
            sessionStorage.token = "";
...
```

gcf_generals_post.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* Carreguem textos => Tot el contingut dels elements de classe gcf_mlg */

    $.getJSON('gcf_mlg/mlg_ca.json')
    .done(function(data) {
        $('.gcf_mlg').each(function() {
            var template = $(this).html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $(this).empty().html(html);
        });
    });

});
```

I suspect that changing the input content with $(this).html(...) removes the keypress event, but I don't know how to solve it. Obviously, I did hard googling before posting this question.

Anyone can put some light on it?

Regards,

Seak

Comment: Are you sure gcf_bLogin remains after applying mustache? Probably that tag is removed after applying mustache, becoz of which keypress event does not get applied. What does your console say? Any error is thrown?

Comment: No errors to console. And the click events inside login.js works

Comment: After doing the $(this).empty().html(html); the keypress disapears and the debugger seems to show the input tag as a new element (but with exactly the same attributes except the mustached one).

Comment: Note that the {{...}} in the button are on the text inside tag but the {{...}} in the input is the placeholder attribute. That's the difference. I think that aplying .html(..) it's considered as a new object.

Comment: It also looses the value $("#user").val(localStorage.usuari);